# Pandas Series Rolling With Strings

Tags: python, pandas

This code raises an Exception (as expected):

```
import pandas as pd

def myfunc(x):
    raise Exception()

pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).rolling(3).apply(myfunc)
```

This code does not raise an Exception:

```
pd.Series(["A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A"]).rolling(3).apply(myfunc)
```

Also, this raises no Exception:

```
pd.Series(["A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A"]).rolling(3).apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))
```

Question: Why is `myfunc()` not being called in the second and third example? Am I missing something? Can't I use `rolling()` on object columns?

Comment: No, you are not missing anything. It's just not called for object Series.